# How to use Hibernate <subselect>:

Tags: hibernate

i am new to hibernate. i need to understand the following questions :

(1) What is subselect in hibernate mapping?

(2) How to map subselect in hbm file?

(3) If i retrieve values using subselect then how to get the retrieved values in java Action class.

Answer (score 7):

1. Based on the description given in [section 5.1.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class), the `subselect` element is used to define a read-only/immutable entity which is based on the results of an arbitrary native query.
2. From the same source, one simply uses `subselect` within a `class` element instead of the `table` attribute and then uses the column names defined in the query as column names in the property mapping. (*the following is taken verbatim from section 5.1.3*)

   ```
   <class name="Summary">
     <subselect>
       select item.name, max(bid.amount), count(*)
       from item
       join bid on bid.item_id = item.id
       group by item.name
     </subselect>
     <synchronize table="item"/>
     <synchronize table="bid"/>
     <id name="name"/>
     ...
   </class>
   ```
3. After you create a mapping using columns from the query in the `subselect` element, you should be able to access the properties just as you would for any other entity.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to model subselects, you can create queries that uses them. Check: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

(Edit: example from the link above)

```
String hql = "from Cat as fatcat "+
             "where fatcat.weight > ( "+
             "  select avg(cat.weight) from DomesticCat cat "+
             ")";
List fatcats = session.createQuery(hql);
```