# How can I use fetch join with @OneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have entities Post, PostDetail.
Those are in one to one relationship, and PostDetail is optional.

```
class Post {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private Strint contents;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private PostDetail postDetail;
}

class PostDetail {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private boolean duplicated;

    @OneToOne
    private Post post;
}

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {
    @Transactional
    @Query("SELECT a FROM Post a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.postDetail")
    public Page<Post> getAll(Example<Post> example, Pageable pageable);

    @Transactional
    @Query("SELECT a FROM Post a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.postDetail")
    public List<Post> getAll();
}
```

When application is booting up, exception occurs.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list ...

What is the problem? I'm trying this to avoid N+1 problem when querying post list (getAll()).

---

Sorry, I modified my question.

Both of two PostRepository's methods make errors.

first getAll() throws error "query specified join fetching ..."

second getAll() throws error

> org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Unknown column 'postdetail1_.post_id' in 'field list'

Comment: This looks fine to me (except for the useless Transactional annotation). My guess is that the exception is about another query. Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Weird. The owner of the fetched association clearly *is* present in the select list. It might be an issue with `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, does the code work if you remove the annotation? A workaround could be to declare the default fetching strategy using hibernate's `@Fetch` annotation and drop the `JOIN FETCH` altogether

Comment: I modified question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid 1+N queries issue you can use EntityGraph. Just override 'findAll' methods in your custom Repo and use EntityGraph annotation on them, like this:

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"postDetail"})
    Page<Post> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"postDetail"})
    List<Post> findAll();
}
```

Comment: It works! Even my sub is shared and used standalone, without link to base (uni-directional relationship). I fetch entire table of bases (because of external csv update). It cost couple of seconds now, you save my day!

Answer (score 1):

For you are working with [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), the type of `id` in `Post` should accord with `ID` in `JpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>`, just do some modifications:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
class Post {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String contents;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postDetail_id")//assume this is the name
    private PostDetail postDetail;
}
```

And you don't have to define a query for a `getAll()`, Spring Data JPA provides some embedded implementations for usual queries, just invoke them:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S entity); 

    T findOne(ID primaryKey);       

    Iterable<T> findAll();          

    Long count();                   

    void delete(T entity);          

    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);  

    // … more functionality omitted.
}
```

So the `PostRepository` just be like:

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

}
```

Then you can test it in your unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll(){
        repo.findAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindById(){
        repo.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, second getAll() problem is solved. but, I can't use findAll() because that makes too many queries.

Comment: Eventually I should use first getAll() for page navigation. How can I use FETCH JOIN with pageable?

Comment: @chaeyk I'm pretty sure you would realize what the problem is, and thus how to fix it, it you read the stack trace of the exception. I asked you to post it, but you didn't. Hint: when using a Pageable, Spring needs to execute a query to count the total number of elements.

Comment: @JBNizet No, I couldn't find a solution. Second getAll() was my fault. I removed PostDetail.post, and problem got away. But when there is Example and Pageable parameter, I couldn't use fetch join.