# Why hibernate generates ~500 SQL queries?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When trying to optimize MySQ slow queries generated by Hibernate 4.2 in a legacy project, I found out that the code below generates nearly 500 SQL queries (with many duplicates) :

```
class MyDAO {
    public List<Message> findMessages() {
        Session session = MyHibernateUtils.openSession();

        String queryStr = "SELECT DISTINCT m FROM Message m "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.types types "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.mainType mainType "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.place place "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.building building "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.city city "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.kind kind "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.domain domain "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.action action "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.customParameterA customParameterA "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.customParameterB customParameterB "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.scheduleEvents scheduleEvents "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.comments comments "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.messageLastActivities messageLastActivities "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.customListA customListA "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.childEvents childEvents "
                + " LEFT JOIN fetch m.parentEvent parentEvent "
                + " WHERE ...";

        List<Message> messages;
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();

            Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);
            query.setTimeout(10);

            messages = query.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return messages;
    }
}
```

How can I avoid having so many SQL queries ?

I don't know if it helps but there are many onyToMany and manyToMany relationships between the entities.

Thank for your help.

Comment: ORM frameworks most off the time works that way... they need to fire a extra `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1`to find the related entiy

Comment: @RaymondNijland No they don't. Well, in the worst case scenario they do that, but that's avoidable most of the time and certainly with Hibernate. Only a very naive ORM would do that, as it would kill performance and make the framework pretty much worthless.

Comment: As for the OP, enable SQL logging for Hibernate (look around, I don't remember how it's done off the top of my head) and see *what* queries are executed. That'll allow you to pin point the cause, which might be just a single N+1 query that you need to fix.

Comment: true @Kayaman ..

Comment: @Kayaman yep they do and raymond is right. Eagar fetching usually requires additional actions (like adding annotations or joins)

Comment: Double check if those extra queries comes from code you have shown us.

Comment: @Antoniossss double checked, it is.

Comment: I think u are wrong, but ok, wrap messages = query.list(); with some START-END log messages, turn on SQL logging and show us the output.

Comment: @Antoniossss Eager fetching requires joins and more complex logic, but provides better performance. He's already using it through `LEFT JOIN FETCH` (but perhaps missing a lazily initialized collection).

Comment: @Antoniossss thank you for your help :). That's what I did, trust me I'm not wrong about it. Sorry I can't show you the output, this is a proprietary software I'm not allowed to do this.

Comment: You could always anonymise logs, nothing wrong about that. But its your choice. As for now, without seeing actual mapping, I see no reason why hibernate would generate more than 1 query, especially that you dont event want to show us what kind of queries it is generating.

Comment: @RomainCiaccafava and as for proprietary software, you have already give away part of your domain model, I dont see why prepared statements should be more protected than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the queries hibernate is generating, to see which table is accessed frequently.

You have to `join fetch` entities related by your `related entities` as well, See here:

[Hibernate is doing multiple select requests instead one (using join fetch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27935761/hibernate-is-doing-multiple-select-requests-instead-one-using-join-fetch)

I personally prefer lazy loading with an annotated `@BatchSize()` to keep the lazy-query-count small. Just using a Batch-Size of 2 will cut your query count in half then.

Also have a look at the `@Cache` Annotation which can reduce your query count in a significant way. (Just thinking of all the almost static stuff like city/building/type/domain and the like)

Comment: Correct ! Thank you @dognose, after adding some missing related entities, the number of queries has largely decreased.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your relationship design, default value of `Fetch` in `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` is `LAZY`, that means for loading related record in child entity (when you call getter method) hibernate executes one more query to load that record (for example: `select * from foo where id = ?`) , so if loaded entity (main entity) contains many child entities such as `ManyToMany` or `OneToMany` you will see many queries in console. 
To void these queries, you can set `Fetch` to `EAGER` but this is not recommended on optimization.

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {

@ManyToMany(Fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<Foo> foos;

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Moodi for your response !  Does the use of `left join fetch` isn't already forcing every `*ToMany` dependencies to be eagerly fetched ?

Comment: Yep it will fetch properties.

Comment: You can use for entities inside children entities.